# Read file from SVN without having local(working) copy

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I need to read the contents of the file by using the url of the file and without having the local copy.

```
eg Url : https://10.0.8.45/svn/Repos/Project/ReadMe.txt
```

We need to run another script based on values in the above url. We are running the script in client side, so we don't know the Repository Path here in order use "svnlook cat" command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

svn cat URL@HEAD - in your case:

```
 https://10.0.8.45/svn/Repos/Project/trunk/ReadMe.txt@HEAD
```

Should do the job - *assuming standard svn project layout*.

Answer (score 1):

`svn cat URL@REV` in common case

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at the most recent copy of the file:

```
$ svn cat https://10.0.8.45/svn/Repos/Project/ReadMe.txt > ReadMe.txt
```

This will print out the file onto your terminal and redirect it to a file called `ReadMe.txt`.

If you need a different revision of that file, you can use the `-r` parameter:

```
$ svn cat -r2323 https://10.0.8.45/svn/Repos/Project/ReadMe.txt > ReadMe.txt
```

If that file has moved, you may need to add the `@`to *pin* the repository view. The `@` basically says _The way the repository was laid out at this revision. For example, you need revision 1234, but that revision was at `https://10.0.8.45/sv/Repos/Project/other/ReadMe.txt`, you will need to do this:

```
$ svn cat -r1234 https://10.0.8.45/svn/Repos/Project/ReadMe.txt@1234
```

If users need to do this alot, you should look into [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org) or [Sventon](http://sventon.org). These are browser based repository browsers. I like Sventon. I find it pretty easy to setup, and you can download zipped up versions of file. It's also pretty fast, and you don't need Sventon on the same system as your repository.